# Подключение файлов через классы

Tags: php

Уважаемые решил задуматься о способах подключения фаилов через классы подскажите хороший мануал. Желательно на русском где будут расписаны методы и приемущества классов. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: а кто такие фалы?))

Comment: А кто сказал что файлы нужно через классы подключать? Если вы не используете в коде ООП, то зачем вам подключать файлы именно через классы?

Comment: Я и хочу поизучать ООП

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подгрузки классов [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

А так, проще создай просто метод типа инклуд_оанс, и там может сразу условие на существование файла сделать и так далее)) 
А по урокам, [вот](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php) самый хороший)